# Using sed between specific lines only

Tags: regex, unix, sed

I have this sed command for removing the spaces after commas.

```bash
sed -e 's/,\s\+/,/g' example.txt
```

How can I change it that, it will make the modification between only specific line numbers.

(e.g. between second and third lines).

Comment: Are those specific line numbers are known at the point when you invoke the sed, or there are regions in the file which depend on the data itself? Like the sed should be active only between certain start and end markers? In that case I would use `awk`, because you can keep state variables between lines.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Use:

```bash
sed '2,3s/,\s\+/,/g' example.txt
```

This will apply the regex `/,\s\+/` only in the lines numbered 2 to 3 (inclusive) and substitute the match with `,`.

Answer (score 11):

Since OSX (BSD sed) has some syntax differences to linux (GNU) sed, thought I'd add the following from some hard-won notes of mine:

OSX (BSD) SED find/replace within (address) block (start and end point patterns(/../) or line #s) in same file ([via](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-25) & [via](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/sed-display-text/) & [via](http://www.alexonlinux.com/sed-the-missing-manual#sed_addresses) & section 4.20 [here](http://www.grok2.com/sedfaq4.html)):

Syntax:

```
$ sed '/start_pattern/,/end_pattern/ [operations]' [target filename]
```

**Standard find/replace examples:**

```
$ sed -i '' '2,3 s/,\s\+/,/g' example.txt
$ sed -i '' '/DOCTYPE/,/body/ s/,\s\+/,/g' example.txt
```

Find/replace example with complex operator and grouping (cannot operate without grouping syntax due to stream use of standard input). All statements in grouping must be on separate lines, or separated w/ semi-colons:

**Complex Operator Example (will delete entire line containing a match):**

```
$ sed -i '' '2,3 {/pattern/d;}' example.txt
```

**Multi-file find + sed:**

```
$ find ./ -type f -name '*.html' | xargs sed -i '' '/<head>/,/<\/head>/ {/pattern/d; /pattern2/d;}'
```

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -e '2,3!b;s/,\s\+/,/g' example.txt
```

This version can be useful if you later want to add more commands to process the desired lines.

Comment: I suspect there's good information here. But I have to admit, I don't follow what's going on. Its not obvious to me why the `!b` and `;` are present and how they are useful later. Perhaps you can explain things a bit.

Comment: please clarify what is going on there.