# Using regexes to remove lines between two strings

Tags: regex, bash

I'm currently making a script that will show the next departures from a metro stop right by me.

I have a pattern  `(\b\d$|Westbound)` that will capture the line number and direction. However, how do one remove the lines in between? Searching around for it has not given me any results for this.

Consider the output:

```
5
Ringen via Storo
12 min
Eastbound

4
Vestli via Storo
16:10
Westbound

5
Vestli via Majorstuen
16:11
Eastbound

5
Ringen via Majorstuen
16:12
Westbound
```

In the format of:

```
Line
Name of line
Time
Direction
```

The question is, is there any way using sed that I can filter out all lines going, say, Westbound so that the only lines printed would be:

```
5
Ringen via Storo
12 min
Eastbound

5
Vestli via Majorstuen
16:11
Eastbound
```

This would mean remove any segment of text that begins with *5* and ends with *Westbound*. Is this possible with regexes and built in tools in bash, or would it be better to find a workaround for this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Okay so you know pretty well what you want to do, I suggest that you try to actually do it. StackOverflow is not the place where people implement programs for you, it's the place where you implement the program and people help you when you have a specific question.

Comment: Is the above output produced by a script the _you_ wrote? If so, why not modify that script?

Comment: Regex might be _part_ of the solution here, but I think you'll need an additional tool to read in and process each paragraph.  Maybe sed can do this, Java and C# certainly can.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16202900/using-sed-between-specific-lines-only might be your solution

Comment: `/.*\n.*\n.*\nWestbound\n*/` ?

Comment: awk is what you are looking for.  Use with `RS=""`, `FS="\n"` and `$4 ~ /EastBound/`

Comment: First of all thanks for the answers, everyone. Been trying a little around with solutions/suggestions above, and awk worked nicely. Thank you again, everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Executing this -

```
echo '5
Ringen via Storo
12 min
Eastbound

4
Vestli via Storo
16:10
Westbound

5
Vestli via Majorstuen
16:11
Eastbound

5
Ringen via Majorstuen
16:12
Westbound' | gawk 'BEGIN {
    FS="\n"
    RS=""
}
$4 != "Westbound" {
    print
}'
```

- generates the following output -

```
5
Ringen via Storo
12 min
Eastbound
5
Vestli via Majorstuen
16:11
Eastbound
```

Comment: This did exactly what I was looking for. Thank you for taking your time!