# How to determine the line number of the last occurrence of a string in a file using a shell script?

Tags: shell, zsh

In my own efforts to solve [this opened question](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/98034/cannot-boot-other-linux-distributions-via-the-grub-bootloader-setup-by-fedora-25-initrd-and-linux-not-found/) of mine at Ask Fedora I have been trying to determine the line number of the last occurrence of the string `Fedora` in my `/boot/grub2/grub.cfg` file. Is there a way to do this using `sed`, `grep`, `awk` or any other common shell (specifically the Z Shell, if the specific Unix shell I am using matters) commands? For example, the command I want would return `127` (i.e., line 127, which is where the last occurrence of the string `Fedora` occurs) for [this grub.cfg](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/abee709cebd20ea05b6cb558c04a9456) file. I would use this shell command to determine this line number so that I can feed it to sed (with a `sed` command similar to that in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16202900/1876983), as I only want to replace a regex in lines after those that mention Fedora).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using awk:

```
awk '/Fedora/ { ln = FNR } END { print ln }'
```

Using grep:

```
grep -n 'Fedora' | tail -n1 | cut -d: -f1
```

Using the shell (tested in bash only):

```
unset ln lnr
while read -r; do
    ((lnr++))
    case "$REPLY" in
        *Fedora*) ln="$lnr";;
    esac
done < grub.cfg
echo $ln
```

Comment: I tested your shell solution in Zsh and it worked fine, mentioning for future reference if anyone is interested. I will personally be using your awk solution as it's more compact.